# I am not able to Parse the json file. It begins with array

Tags: android, json, parsing, getjson

The following JSON starts with an array type which I am having a lots of problem to Parse. Please help.

[{"type":"1","name":"ABC","start_date":"5","end_date":null,"time":"00:00:00","description":"abc","venue":"","v_id":"1","c1name":"","c1phno":"","c1email":"","c2name":"","c2phno":"","c2email":""}]

Please help me out if possible.

Comment: Is there a question here? I just see JSON.

Comment: @cricket_007 Sorry about that. I edited the question.

Comment: There is still no code with what you have tried or are trying to parse out of the JSON. Please clearly explain in your post what your expected results should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to get the data as a JSONArray?

It would look like this:

```
  String json = "your json data";
  JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
  JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

  String type = jsonObject.getString("type");
  String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
```

And so on...

Comment: If there is more than one object, upto what should I run my for loop?

Comment: Just like you would for a normal array "for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)"...perhaps you should look at the documentation for JSONArray and JSONObject in the documentation